# Best pratices to access large data in Azure Databricks with R

Tags: r, azure, data.table, databricks, sparkr

New in `Azure` and `Databricks`, I am trying to access a large set of data, on which I would like to run an R process (written in `data.table` and which runs well locally).

I'm not comfortable with the right terms or how the entire Azure environment works, but for now, my data is present in 3 formats :

- table
- paquet
- csv

**First attempt** (and the most logical for me) : a classical `fread` on csv files.
On small files, all is alright. On 'big' files (3Go), it takes many, many minutes while locally, it only takes a handful of seconds.

[image]

Why is it much longer than locally ?

**Second attempt** with `SparkR` on csv files and `collect()` to work with `data.table`
[image]

But `collect()` return an error :
[image]

Is there something I can do to set this ?

**Third attempt** : same as above on delta files, with the same type of error

[image]

**Fourth attempt** : SQL request from `SparkR` but `collect` still return the same error

[image]

Is one of my attempts better than another ?
Am I on the right track ?
Am I missing something ?

Any help or advice will be very helpful.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain properly formatted text, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding loading from DBFS it is object storage in cloud not local storage so loading time naturally will be much longer.

Regarding error you can adjust Spark config but is not recommended as you can get out of memory error:

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize <X>g
```

You can adjust it in cluster spark config
[image]

The best solution is to use more instances (so there will be automatically more partitions - this limit apply per partition, instance RAM memory size is also important but better usually just add more instances - scale horizontally). Enable auto-scaling is recommended in case of big data set.

Please don't use collect() as it reads all your dataframe on driver to object so it will not work. Generally this function is not recommended even for smaller datasets. If you want to diagnose your dataframe please use functions like .first() or .show with limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a little clearer. But as a new user of this environment, I do not understand everything  :)  How can I adjust Spark config for example ? How can I use more instances ? (You are right, data is in the cloud. My cluster has 252Go and 72 cores).

Comment: wow this cluster is already pretty big. I will update my answer with more details in few hours. Please don't use collect() as it reads all your dataframe on driver to object so it will not work. Generally this function is not recommended even for smaller datasets. If you want to diagnoze your dataframe please use functions like .first() .show with limit.

Comment: Until now, I haven't found a better way than ```collect()``` to run my "local" script written in ```data.table```... Can't wait to read your update !

Comment: but what exactly do you want to achieve? try display(df) also

Comment: I need to run a whole script that I wrote in ```data.table```. But I think I'll have to rewrite it in ```sparkr```, right ? But it seems more complex to me than it sounds. I have been trying to create a new column for a long time using ```strsplit``` on another column without success...